# ¿Por que mi input Select Option no selecciona el valor por defecto?

Tags: php, html

Buenos días, tengo el siguiente problema; Lo que sucede es que tengo un select option de la siguiente forma:

```
<select id="periodicidad" name="periodicidad" required>
                        <option disabled selected value="<?php echo $periodicidad;?>"><?php echo $periodicidad;?></option>
                        <option name="2" value="2">2</option>
                        <option name="3" value="3">3</option>
                        <option name="4" value="4">4</option>
                        </select>
```

Este select option esta recibiendo una variable que traigo de una consulta de una BD, lo que sucede es que al indicarle al select el valor (que es un numero), me lo marca como si fuera un valor NULL, de tal forma que al darle al submit button me retorna lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Apesar de que en la página se observa de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay algo que este haciendo mal? Agradezco cualquier recomendación o posible solución a este problema, saludos!

Comment: de seguro lo que viene sea un string y deberas convertirlo a numero si quieres operar con el

Comment: El problema es por el atributo `disabled`, no permite seleccionar la opción por defecto.

Comment: veo varias cosas raras... primero un disabled junto a un selected... quizas funciona pero vamos, no tiene sentido... y luego pones names a los options, cosa que confunde al name del select supongo. Quita como mínimo los name de los options, pues mucho me temo que sea eso. Y si lo que quieres es que el 3 sea el selected, quitale el disabled pues no lo va a tener en cuenta y por eso el valor null supongo.

Comment: @masterguru Hola, te queria comentar que en efecto fue el "disabled" del elemento select , elimine este disabled y automaticamente me retorna el valor que debe ser, supongo que añadire alguna funcion para cuando se des-seleccione este valor se elimine también del elemento(Para que no se repitan opciones), muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: De nada, pero el agradecimiento tambien es para Triby, el lo dijo primero... pero quita los name tambien, no tienen sentido... en los option el name que manda es el de su select, si lo hay.  Si lo que quieres es referenciar a los option de algun modo mediante javascript usa `id=` en lugar de `name=`, pues el name es para formularios más bien.

Comment: @Triby, muchas gracias por la indicación, agradezco bastante la ayuda, y a ti masterguru, implementaré todas tus recomendaciones en este y en futuros proyectos, muchas gracias y bendiciones para sus conocimientos!

Answer (score 2):

Tenemos dos cuestiones aquí,
Primero el selected:
Tienes que tener en cuenta que al vos usar el selected tienes que usar una lógica para indicar cual es el que se seleccionó más allá del disabled que pusiste.

```
<select>
    <option selected disabled><?php echo $periodicidad;?></option>
    <?php 
    for($i = 1; $i<5; $i++){
            echo '<option '. ( ($i == $periodicidad) ? 'selected' : '' ) .' value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

En cuánto a lo segundo

Creo que no estás tomando del "post" la variable que enviaste

Intenta poner un:

`var_dump($_POST);`

Para ver qué enviaste al darle a submit

Comment: Hola, gracias por la recomendación del código, la implementaré y editare la respuesta con respecto al resultado que obtuve (Ya indique en los comentarios de arriba cual fue el error, pero implementaré esta solución para mejor resolución y eficiencia) Gracias!